# Replace white space between strings

Tags: file, sed

I have a file like

```
>TCONS_00000066 +1
PPAAARTDLSPPQHVLHVYKRYGPPRQRRRPCPQTWWWQLPHRAAATHPRGEGPRASNPTRQQHFILVYNFSSFLSSWLSLSLLSSPFCYLYICDCHGNTEDEGPLMY*LVSSSLGAFVCKDFHLIDLLDLLFWIEAGYLHAVLHTILQSGRSDR*SRPKYRLTELSVCISVRTSSVINSKC*HN
>TCONS_00000066 +2
RRLLRAPTCHHPSTSSTYTSATVHRGSVDVLVRKHGGGSFLIEQQQLILEGKGPELLILHGNNTLYLCIISLRF*VHGYLCLSYLLPFAISIFVIAMEIQKTRGR*CIDL*VLVWGLSFARIFI*LIFLICYFGSKLATFMPCCIPYFSLVGQTDDRDRSID*PNFRFVYL*GQVLSSIQNVNII
>TCONS_00000066 +3
AGCCAHRLVTTPARPPRIQALRSTAAASTSLSANMVVAASSSSSSNSSSRGRAQSF*SYTATTLYTCV*FLFVSEFMAIFVSLIFSLLLSLYL*LPWKYRRRGAADVLTCEF*FGGFRLQGFSFD*SS*FVILDRSWLPSCRVAYHTSVWSVRPMIETEVSINRTFGLYICEDKFCHQFKMLT*
>TCONS_00000066 -1
YYVNILN**QNLSSQIYKPKVRLIDTSVSIIGLTDQTEVWYATRHEGSQLRSKITNQEDQSNENPCKRKPPN*NSQVNTSAAPRLLYFHGNHKYRDSKREKIRETKIAMNSETKRNYTQV*SVVAV*D*KLWALPLEDELLLLDEEAATTMFADKDVDAAAVDRSACIRGGRAGVVTSRCAQQPA
>TCONS_00000066 -2
IMLTF*IDDRTCPHRYTNRKFG*SILRSRSSV*PTRLKYGMQHGMKVASFDPK*QIKKINQMKILANESPQTRTHKSIHQRPLVFCISMAITNIEIAKGRR*ERQR*P*TQKRREIIHKYKVLLPCRIRSSGPFPSRMSCCCSMRKLPPPCLRTRTSTLPRWTVALVYVEDVLGW*QVGARSSRR
>TCONS_00000066 -3
LC*HFELMTELVLTDIQTESSVNRYFGLDHRSDRPD*SMVCNTA*R*PASIQNNKSRRSIK*KSLQTKAPKLELTSQYISGPSSSVFPWQSQI*R*QKGEDKRDKDSHELRNEEKLYTSIKCCCRVGLEALGPSPRG*VAAAR*GSCHHHVCGQGRRRCRGGP*RLYTWRTCWGGDKSVRAAAG
>TCONS_00000130 +1
LPARPRLQGALQRHRGGKPINQSINQWW*LGQLKTKKERSN*SSC*IVKWYAGEGGDSGSGGGGRGDGGGDGEPARRHHARRRPPRQELPLQVDEPVRANEEGWVQGSWHQAARHGTGRFLQRRAHPNRDHQFARTTA*NPLPNVHPSAGRAMEKKIKGKEEKMKSPCITN*FVMMQAAVRVRSSLIGSIR*ICFTKGATDRLSWLAVWVHIHTTQTQILTI*PFAKNIFTNEQLPKLISNLTLLLNAKSCGAEFRHLSAK*YGAECTLAR*LSLPSAVARHSAPADVALRCLSSAPHDLALSKKVRFEISFGSGSFVKLVFTKG*IVKICATQTHSQEDMNIK*SREGHGFSPGFVPFGCTCTEMIYVVGLTDTKEHM***MIFVLLCQSFTLVFLTCFLSSTVVLRIQ*PQLMRLKWILAN*AYSLIFWLMVIL
>TCONS_00000130 +2
FQLALAFRELCNGIAEVNQSTNQSINGGSWVNSKQRKKEAINHLVEL*NGMQAKVEIVVREGEVGETVVATVNQLAATTLVVGLHDKSFLYRSTNPYERMRRVGCRVLGIRQHATARDGSFNAELTQIETINLHVPPPKIPFPMFTLPLGVLWRKRSKAKKRK*SHHASQINL**CRLQCELGAH*LDQSDEFVLPKEQLTD*AG*LSGYIYTRHKHKF*QFNPLQKIFLQMNSYQNLFQI*PFCLTPNRVALNLDTSAPNSMALNVRWHADLVSHPPWHGIQRQLTWR*GV*VPRHMI*R*AKRSDLK*VLAAVHL*N*FLQRVKLSKFVRHKHTHKKT*TSSEAGRGTVSHLDLCHLVVLVQR*SMLLD*QTPRNTCSSK*FLFYFVKVLHLYS*PVSCLAQ*C*EFSNLS**D*NGYWPIKLIASSFGLWLYL
>TCONS_00000130 +3
SSSPSPSGSSATASRR*TNQPINQSMVVVGSTQNKERKKQLIILLNCEMVCRRRWR*WFGRGRSGRRWWRR*TSSPPPRSSSASTTRASSTGRRTRTSE*GGLGAGFLASGSTPRHGTVPSTPSSPKSRPSICTYHRLKSPSQCSPFRWACYGEKDQRQRRENEVTMHHKLICDDAGCSAS*ELTDWINPMNLFYQRSN*QIELASCLGTYTHDTNTNFDNLTLCKKYFYK*TATKTYFKSDPFA*RQIVWR*I*TPQRQIVWR*MYVGTLT*SPIRRGTAFSAS*RGAEVSKFRAT*FSVEQKGQI*NKFWQRFICKISFYKGLNCQNLCDTNTLTRRHEHQVKQGGARFLTWICAIWLYLYRDDLCCWIDRHQGTHVVVNDFCFTLSKFYTCIPDLFLV*HSSVKNSVTSVDEIKMDIGQLSL*PHLLAYGYTY
>TCONS_00000130 -1
ISITISQKMRL*A*LANIHFNLIN*GY*ILNTTVLDKKQVRNTSVKL*QSKTKIIYYYMCSLVSVNPTT*IISVQVQPNGTNPGEKPCPSLLHLMFMSSCECVCVAQILTI*PFVKTNFTNEPLPKLISNLTFLLNAKSCGAELRHLSATSAGAECRATADGRLSQRANVHSAPYYLALRCLNSAPHDLALSKRVRFEISFGSCSFVKIFFAKG*IVKICVCVVCICTQTASQLNLSVAPLVKQIHRIDPISELLTRTAACIITN*FVMHGDFIFSSLPLIFFSIARPAEG*TLGRGF*AVVRAN*WSRFG*ARR*RNRPVPWRAA*CQEPCTQPSSFARTGSSTCRGSSCRGGRRRAWWRRAGSPSPPPSPRPPPPEPLSPPSPAYHFTIQQDD*LLLSFFVLS*PNYHH*LIDWLIGLPPRCRCRAP*RRGRAG
>TCONS_00000130 -2
```

I want to remove the space between strings in the id line.

The new file should be like

```
>TCONS_00000066_+1
PPAAARTDLSPPQHVLHVYKRYGPPRQRRRPCPQTWWWQLPHRAAATHPRGEGPRASNPTRQQHFILVYNFSSFLSSWLSLSLLSSPFCYLYICDCHGNTEDEGPLMY*LVSSSLGAFVCKDFHLIDLLDLLFWIEAGYLHAVLHTILQSGRSDR*SRPKYRLTELSVCISVRTSSVINSKC*HN
>TCONS_00000066_+2
RRLLRAPTCHHPSTSSTYTSATVHRGSVDVLVRKHGGGSFLIEQQQLILEGKGPELLILHGNNTLYLCIISLRF*VHGYLCLSYLLPFAISIFVIAMEIQKTRGR*CIDL*VLVWGLSFARIFI*LIFLICYFGSKLATFMPCCIPYFSLVGQTDDRDRSID*PNFRFVYL*GQVLSSIQNVNII
>TCONS_00000066_+3
AGCCAHRLVTTPARPPRIQALRSTAAASTSLSANMVVAASSSSSSNSSSRGRAQSF*SYTATTLYTCV*FLFVSEFMAIFVSLIFSLLLSLYL*LPWKYRRRGAADVLTCEF*FGGFRLQGFSFD*SS*FVILDRSWLPSCRVAYHTSVWSVRPMIETEVSINRTFGLYICEDKFCHQFKMLT*
>TCONS_00000066_-1
YYVNILN**QNLSSQIYKPKVRLIDTSVSIIGLTDQTEVWYATRHEGSQLRSKITNQEDQSNENPCKRKPPN*NSQVNTSAAPRLLYFHGNHKYRDSKREKIRETKIAMNSETKRNYTQV*SVVAV*D*KLWALPLEDELLLLDEEAATTMFADKDVDAAAVDRSACIRGGRAGVVTSRCAQQPA
>TCONS_00000066_-2
IMLTF*IDDRTCPHRYTNRKFG*SILRSRSSV*PTRLKYGMQHGMKVASFDPK*QIKKINQMKILANESPQTRTHKSIHQRPLVFCISMAITNIEIAKGRR*ERQR*P*TQKRREIIHKYKVLLPCRIRSSGPFPSRMSCCCSMRKLPPPCLRTRTSTLPRWTVALVYVEDVLGW*QVGARSSRR
>TCONS_00000066_-3
LC*HFELMTELVLTDIQTESSVNRYFGLDHRSDRPD*SMVCNTA*R*PASIQNNKSRRSIK*KSLQTKAPKLELTSQYISGPSSSVFPWQSQI*R*QKGEDKRDKDSHELRNEEKLYTSIKCCCRVGLEALGPSPRG*VAAAR*GSCHHHVCGQGRRRCRGGP*RLYTWRTCWGGDKSVRAAAG
>TCONS_00000130_+1
LPARPRLQGALQRHRGGKPINQSINQWW*LGQLKTKKERSN*SSC*IVKWYAGEGGDSGSGGGGRGDGGGDGEPARRHHARRRPPRQELPLQVDEPVRANEEGWVQGSWHQAARHGTGRFLQRRAHPNRDHQFARTTA*NPLPNVHPSAGRAMEKKIKGKEEKMKSPCITN*FVMMQAAVRVRSSLIGSIR*ICFTKGATDRLSWLAVWVHIHTTQTQILTI*PFAKNIFTNEQLPKLISNLTLLLNAKSCGAEFRHLSAK*YGAECTLAR*LSLPSAVARHSAPADVALRCLSSAPHDLALSKKVRFEISFGSGSFVKLVFTKG*IVKICATQTHSQEDMNIK*SREGHGFSPGFVPFGCTCTEMIYVVGLTDTKEHM***MIFVLLCQSFTLVFLTCFLSSTVVLRIQ*PQLMRLKWILAN*AYSLIFWLMVIL
>TCONS_00000130_+2
FQLALAFRELCNGIAEVNQSTNQSINGGSWVNSKQRKKEAINHLVEL*NGMQAKVEIVVREGEVGETVVATVNQLAATTLVVGLHDKSFLYRSTNPYERMRRVGCRVLGIRQHATARDGSFNAELTQIETINLHVPPPKIPFPMFTLPLGVLWRKRSKAKKRK*SHHASQINL**CRLQCELGAH*LDQSDEFVLPKEQLTD*AG*LSGYIYTRHKHKF*QFNPLQKIFLQMNSYQNLFQI*PFCLTPNRVALNLDTSAPNSMALNVRWHADLVSHPPWHGIQRQLTWR*GV*VPRHMI*R*AKRSDLK*VLAAVHL*N*FLQRVKLSKFVRHKHTHKKT*TSSEAGRGTVSHLDLCHLVVLVQR*SMLLD*QTPRNTCSSK*FLFYFVKVLHLYS*PVSCLAQ*C*EFSNLS**D*NGYWPIKLIASSFGLWLYL
>TCONS_00000130_+3
SSSPSPSGSSATASRR*TNQPINQSMVVVGSTQNKERKKQLIILLNCEMVCRRRWR*WFGRGRSGRRWWRR*TSSPPPRSSSASTTRASSTGRRTRTSE*GGLGAGFLASGSTPRHGTVPSTPSSPKSRPSICTYHRLKSPSQCSPFRWACYGEKDQRQRRENEVTMHHKLICDDAGCSAS*ELTDWINPMNLFYQRSN*QIELASCLGTYTHDTNTNFDNLTLCKKYFYK*TATKTYFKSDPFA*RQIVWR*I*TPQRQIVWR*MYVGTLT*SPIRRGTAFSAS*RGAEVSKFRAT*FSVEQKGQI*NKFWQRFICKISFYKGLNCQNLCDTNTLTRRHEHQVKQGGARFLTWICAIWLYLYRDDLCCWIDRHQGTHVVVNDFCFTLSKFYTCIPDLFLV*HSSVKNSVTSVDEIKMDIGQLSL*PHLLAYGYTY
>TCONS_00000130_-1
ISITISQKMRL*A*LANIHFNLIN*GY*ILNTTVLDKKQVRNTSVKL*QSKTKIIYYYMCSLVSVNPTT*IISVQVQPNGTNPGEKPCPSLLHLMFMSSCECVCVAQILTI*PFVKTNFTNEPLPKLISNLTFLLNAKSCGAELRHLSATSAGAECRATADGRLSQRANVHSAPYYLALRCLNSAPHDLALSKRVRFEISFGSCSFVKIFFAKG*IVKICVCVVCICTQTASQLNLSVAPLVKQIHRIDPISELLTRTAACIITN*FVMHGDFIFSSLPLIFFSIARPAEG*TLGRGF*AVVRAN*WSRFG*ARR*RNRPVPWRAA*CQEPCTQPSSFARTGSSTCRGSSCRGGRRRAWWRRAGSPSPPPSPRPPPPEPLSPPSPAYHFTIQQDD*LLLSFFVLS*PNYHH*LIDWLIGLPPRCRCRAP*RRGRAG
>TCONS_00000130_-2
```

I used `sed` and `tr` but not getting the desired output.

Comment: i used something like sed 's/TCONS_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][[:blank:]]+/TCONS_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_+/g' ORF6frame_orfpredictor.fa >new

Comment: also i used this one sed s/\/\_/g ORF6frame_orfpredictor.fa >new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you're trying to replace spaces with `_` symbol. If yes, then you may consider this,

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/_/g' file
```

OR

```
sed 's/\(TCONS_[0-9]\{8\}\)[[:blank:]]\+/\1_/g' file
```

You need to capture the characters that you want to keep. So here, the chars you want to keep are `TCONS_`+ `8digits`. SO put the the pattern which matches this inside a capturing group, `\(...\)`. And match the following one or more spaces with this `[[:blank:]]\+` pattern. You must need to escape the `+`, so that it would repeat the previous token one or more times or otherwise it would match a literal `+` symbol because basic sed uses `BRE` (*Baisc regular expression*)

Comment: the second command you gave worked good. can you point out my mistake. why my command didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tr`, it's exact purpose is replacing chars by others.

```
tr ' ' '_' < file
```

As an added bonus you can squeeze multiple occurrences int one with the `s` option, like this:

```
tr -s ' ' '_' < file
```

Which has following effect for instance:

```
$ cat a
hello     world           this
is     a      sample       file
$ tr -s ' ' '_' < a
hello_world_this
is_a_sample_file
```

Of course you have to output it into a file and move it back to the original if you want to save the changes in the original file.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you can merge `-s` and `' ' '_'`. Beautiful, +1!